# Question on editing a question and adding a solution (The edit is not by the OP)

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Having recently crossed the 2K rep mark, I am now allowed to review edit's on posts. I came across a rather strange predicament and I am hoping someone can help clear this one out.

I had answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13032537/450534) and there was a pending edit on it. A user (not the OP) edited the question with a solution. Regardless of whether the solution is right or wrong, should such edits be rejected? It's only logical that when there is a provision to provide an answer, such an edit should be rejected.

The OP can of course edit his own post with the solution, but I figured, this should be clarified before I go do something I shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes — an edit that adds a solution or answer to a question should be rejected with the "invalid edit" reason, which states (emphasis mine):

> **invalid edit**
>   This edit is incorrect or **an attempt to reply to** or comment on the existing post.

In this case, it looks like the edit was rejected, so it's all good.

As you imply, it's only logical that if it's an answer, it should be posted as an answer. Why humans can't seem to understand a concept as fundamental as this is beyond my comprehension. (That, or I'm in a very bad mood today.)

Also, ideally, the OP should be post an answer instead of editing their question too; however, the site has a time-based restriction in place for new users to prevent them from misusing the answer field (going back to my rant just above...). In order to get around this they often short-circuit the time restriction by editing their question instead. I believe this is suggested by the site itself, in which case whenever I see such an edit from the OP, I remind them in a comment to turn the edit into an answer once time permits.

Comment: That sounds right. I was on the line on that one considering I had just posted an answer. I did not want a moral dilemma over rejecting the edit. But this does clear it up. Thanks. :-)